# Sealed keyword affects the compiler's opinion on a cast

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I have a situation where I'd like the behaviour of the compiler explained. Given a little code:

```
interface IFoo<T>
{
    T Get();
}

class FooGetter : IFoo<int>
{
    public int Get()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

The following compiles and runs:

```
static class FooGetterGetter
{
    public static IFoo<T> Get<T>()
    {
        return (IFoo<T>)new FooGetter();
    }
}
```

If we make a change to the signature of the `Foo` class and add the `sealed` keyword:

```
sealed class FooGetter : IFoo<int> // etc
```

Then I get a compiler error on the following line:

```
 return (IFoo<T>)new FooGetter();
```

Of:

> Cannot convert type 'MyNamespace.FooGetter' to 'MyNamespace.IFoo<T>'

Can someone explain what is happening here with regards to the `sealed` keyword? This is C# 4 against a .NET 4 project in Visual Studio 2010.

**Update:** interestingly enough I stumbled on that part of the behaviour when I was wondering why the following code fixes it when `sealed` is applied:

```
return (IFoo<T>)(IFoo<int>)new FooGetter();
```

**Update:** just for clarification, it all runs fine when the type of `T` requested is the same as the type of `T` used by the concrete type. If the types differ, the cast fails at runtime with something like:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MyNamespace.StringFoo' to type
>   'MyNamespace.IFoo`1[System.Int32]'

In the above example, `StringFoo : IFoo<string>` and the caller asks to get an `int`.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I would imagine that it has something to do with the fact that `IFoo<T>` is an open generic type whereas `FooGetter` implements `IFoo<int>` which is a closed generic type.

Comment: Just a note: I made sure I got the behaviour defined before posting the question - didn't want to make a fool of myself :-) I can see why it may be allowed, the compiler cannot guarantee what is going on, it only knows that it has a chance of success. But for some reason, it removes that same chance of success when the sealed keyword is present due to it assuming that because it cannot be derived, it cannot match T.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `FooGetter` is an explicit implementation of `IFoo<int>` instead of implementing `IFoo<T>` generically. Since it is sealed, the compiler knows there's no way to cast it to a generic `IFoo<T>` if `T` is anything other than an `int`.  If it were not sealed, the compiler would allow it to compile and throw an exception at runtime if `T` was not an `int`.

If you try to use it with anything other than an `int` (e.g. `FooGetterGetter.Get<double>();`) you get an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MyNamespace.FooGetter' to type 'MyNamespace.IFoo`1[System.Double]'.

What I'm not sure of is why the compiler does *not* generate an error for the non-sealed version. How could your sub-class `FooGetter` such that `new FooGetter()` give you anything that implements `IFoo<{something_other_than_int}>`?

**Update:**

Per [Dan Bryant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206394/dan-bryant) and [Andras Zoltan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157701/andras-zoltan) there are methods to return a derived class from a constructor (or possibly more precisely for *the compiler* to return a different type by analyzing attributes). So technically this is feasible if the class is not sealed.

Comment: +1 but to answer your last question - well - it's an interface - so you can just add another instance of the interface on?  The compiler doesn't see the `new` it only sees an expression of type `FooGetter` which, when not `sealed` could be any type derived from it.

Comment: @DStanley I see your point. Your explanation then also applies to casting twice to get around the sealed keyword. In the cast-twice situation, you know you can cast to an `IFoo<int>` if the concrete type uses `int`, you can then cast from `IFoo<int>` to `IFoo<T>` for the same reason the compiler lets you do `FooGetter` to `IFoo<T>` (were it not sealed) - for some reason it lets any errors occur at runtime.

Comment: To flesh out Andras's point, you could have `SecondFoo : FooGetter, IFoo<double>`. Curious as to why it ignores the `new` in that case, that guarantees no derived types... unless it assumes that a base type could possibly implement the correct interface and doesn't bother looking - leaving errors to runtime.

Comment: @Andras in other words it sees `new FooGetter()` as an expression of type `FooGetter` and doesn't realize that it can't be anything _other_ than a `FooGetter`?

Comment: The compiler will make these static inferences for a sealed class for other types of casts other than generic.  For instance, if you have a sealed class that does not implement IFoo at all, it will rightly complain.  If that same class is unsealed, however, there could be a derived class that implements the interface, so it allows the attempt at a cast.  This appears to be a limitation of the static analysis where the compiler decides that the cast is impossible.  I believe there are also some optimizations that can occur with sealed classes implementing interfaces, so perhaps that's related.

Comment: @D Stanley, it's actually possible for a `new` expression to return a type other than the specified type in the case of 'auto-magic' proxying, though that's an extreme boundary case and should, in principle, be known by the compiler.

Comment: @DStanley - yes; because ultimately it's more efficient from a compiler point of view; and also because it ensures that auto-magic proxying, as Dan has said, but also customised run-times which do more interesting things don't break the code.  Not only that, but scanning the right hand side of expression trees to find a `new` all the time would probably do nasty things to the compiler's performance I think.  Also - imagine how much nastier the C# spec would be to implement!

Comment: @Dan - interesting, I was not aware that it was possible.  Can you post a link that explains in more detail?  I'll edit my answer to reference your explanation.

Comment: @All I'm secretly hoping Eric Lippert will spot this and we can get an answer straight from the horse's mouth about compiler behaviour when sealed is involved. I believe in my case it could "safely" let the error percolate to runtime, as the presence of the sealed keyword gives it no more knowledge as to whether `FooGetter` satisfies `T`, it just says, "hold it, I can guarantee FooGetter is int, and T may or may not be int". Instead of "FooGetter may or may not be T."

Comment: @D Stanley, You can use ProxyAttribute to accomplish this.  Marc Gravell has also pointed out that you can you use this to have `new` return a true null value, though that's an exceedingly evil thing to do.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.proxyattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - don't worry, Mr Lippert is nigh-on omnipresent when it comes to questions on C# - especially on these edge-cases :)

Comment: As this is the highest voted, and due to the extended discussion delving into the issue, I'm happy to mark this as the answer. I might in future ask a question about why the compiler gets a little hypocritical when sealed is involved in this case ;-)

Answer (score 4):

When a class in unsealed any derived class could implement `IFoo<T>`:

```
class MyClass : FooGetter, IFoo<double> { }
```

When `FooGetter` is marked as sealed, the compiler knows that it cannot be possible for any additional implementations of `IFoo<T>` other than `IFoo<int>` could exist for `FooGetter`.

This is good behavior, it allows you to catch problems with your code at compile time instead of at runtime.

The reason that `(IFoo<T>)(IFoo<int>)new FooGetter();` works is because you are now representing your sealed class as `IFoo<int>` which could be implemented by anything. It is also a nice work around as you are not accidentally, but purposefully overriding the compiler check.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the existing answers: This really has nothing to do with the generics used.

Consider this simpler example:

```
interface ISomething
{
}

class OtherThing
{
}
```

Then saying (inside a method):

```
OtherThing ot = XXX;
ISomething st = (ISomething)ot;
```

works just fine. The compiler does not know if an `OtherThing` might be an `ISomething`, so it believes us when we say it will succeed. However, if we change `OtherThing` to a **sealed type** (namely `sealed class OtherThing { }` or `struct OtherThing { }`), then the cast is no longer allowed. The compiler knows it can't go well (except if `ot` were to be `null`, but the rules of C# still disallow the cast from a sealed type to an interface not implemented by that sealed type).

Regarding the update of the question: Writing `(IFoo<T>)(IFoo<int>)new FooGetter()` is not much different than writing `(IFoo<T>)(object)new FooGetter()`. You can "make allowed" any cast (with generics or without) by going through some intermediate type that is certainly/possibly an ancestor to both of the types you want to convert between. It's very much similar to this pattern:

```
void MyMethod<T>(T t)    // no "where" constraints on T
{
  if (typeof(T) = typeof(GreatType))
  {
    var tConverted = (GreatType)(object)t;
    // ... use tConverted here
  }
  // ... other stuff
}
```