# How can I avoid double casting?

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I got the following class hierarchy:

`MssqlDataSource<T>`:`DataSource<T>`:`IDataSource<T>`:`IQueryable<T>`

Inside the `MssqlDataSource` class I got the property:

```
private Table<T> Table { get { return (Table<T>)(IQueryable<T>)this; } }
```

And the double casting (`this` to [`IQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) and then to [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx)) cannot be simplified to `(Table<T>)this` or just `this` because I am getting the compilation error.

---

```
private Table<T> Table { get { return (Table<T>)this; } }
```

Produces the:
[image: Cast error]

---

So how to solve it? How to use only one casting (or better none) to avoid the complilation error? And why does it appear?

Comment: Is `MssqlDataSource<T>` marked as `sealed` by any chance?

Comment: You say that as if it is obvious... but please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912542/sealed-keyword-affects-the-compilers-opinion-on-a-cast) I asked a while ago, might broaden the understanding, but possibly not directly answer it.

Comment: If you're sure why not use return `this as Table<T>`?

Comment: @Aphelion because `as` implies the possible null result. And hence it is slower.

Comment: @AgentFire `as` can actually be faster because it doesn't do a type check on cast. If your item will be the correct type, the end result will behave the same as a cast anyway. It is all to do with compiler guarantees, which is basically moving the onus from the compiler to the runtime.

Comment: `this as <something>` can be null if `this` is not `something`.

Comment: @AgentFire I inderstand that, however you want to remove strong checking (and the error) but you're always expecting the type to be instance of the table Type. Either be 100% sure and use `as`, or just do do manual casting.

Comment: @AgentFire: And it seems that `this` is *not* a `Table<T>`. So why are you casting it to `Table<T>`? I don't understand why you're worrying about *performance* when you haven't even got the code working yet...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Doh, yes - will edit quickly :)

Comment: Okay, thanks everybody, the has been code refactored to be cool. Everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According this:

```
MssqlDataSource<T>:DataSource<T>:IDataSource<T>:IQueryable<T>
```

`MssqlDataSource<T>` doesn't inherits from `Table<T>`.

Why should this casting be worked?