# Why do I get a compilation error when casting a sealed class to an interface it might implement?

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

The following code gives a compiler error CS0030 (compiled with the C# compiler of VS 2012), although the cast might succeed at runtime. Removing the `sealed` keyword, using an `as` cast, or adding an intermediate cast to `object` makes the error go away.

```
  public interface IFunny<out T> { }

  public sealed class Funny<T> : IFunny<T>
  {
    public IFunny<TOther> Cast<TOther> ()
    {
      // error CS0030: Cannot convert type Funny<T>' to 'IFunny<TOther>'.
      return (IFunny<TOther>) this;
    }
  }
```

It seems to me the compiler uses a heuristic for sealed classes only that is too strict in the case of generic interface implementations.

Is it really too strict (in the sense of a bug), or is there a good reason for this error?

**Update:** A clarification to my question: The compiler cannot determine whether there is a relationship between `TOther` and `T` at compile time. The cast would succeed, at runtime, if `TOther` is the same or a base class of `T`, and it would fail in all other cases. This is true no matter whether `Funny<T>` is sealed or not.

The C# compiler does not normally prevent casts that might succeed at runtime. (For example, I can cast an instance of static type `object` to `IComparable`, causing a runtime exception if the instance doesn't really implement that interface.) Why does it do so in this `sealed` case?

Comment: is there a relationship between `T` and `TOther`? How could the compiler know this?

Comment: I'd think the compiler refuses this, because T and TOther are not always compatible. `((IFunny<object>)new Funny<String>())` will probably work ...

Comment: Take a look at this previous SO question; it has some relevant info:
[Sealed Keyword Affects Cast][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912542/sealed-keyword-affects-the-compilers-opinion-on-a-cast

Comment: Since there is no relationship between T and TOther it's impossible that the compiler knows how to cast. But if you instead return `this as IFunny<TOther>`, that would work, as the return value of the cast can also be null.

Comment: @w0lf, Grumbler, Marius - the same would apply if the class isn't marked `sealed`, yet _that_ compiles.

Comment: @w0lf: The compiler can't know whether there is a relationship between `T` and `TOther`. Therefore, I'd expect it to defer that decision to runtime (as it does in the non-`sealed` case).

Answer (score 4):

Since it is `sealed` class, it cannot be inherited down the line by programmer. And in order to have the privileges of casting the objects, you need an inheritance hierarchy.

However, in this case the `sealed` keyword guarantees the compiler that `TOther` cannot be of type `T` in absolutely any case (i.e. It cannot be inherited). Hence the error.

Removing the `sealed` keyword works as it creates opportunity that `TOther` may be of type `T`. Hence the error is gone.

Comment: I don't follow this. Being `sealed` doesn't stop you having a `Funny<string>` and calling `Cast<object>` on it.

Comment: `sealed` guarantees that `Funny<T>` can't be inherited.

Comment: How does `sealed` guarantee the compiler that `TOther` cannot be of type `T`? It does not affect the `T` and `TOther` at all, does it?

First of all, `TOther` could be the same as `T`, then the cast would succeed. Second, `TOther` could be a base class of `T`, in which case it would also work. The compiler has no way of telling whether the cast might succeed, AFAICs.

Comment: When the compiler was written, a sealed type couldn't possibly satisfy any interfaces it was not explicitly documented as implementing.  Code which determined whether a class might implement an interface was probably designed based on that assumption.  Even though the assumption is no longer true, the people working on the compiler have probably not gotten around to fixing the compiler to accommodate that fact.

Answer (score 3):

There is no relationship between TOther and T that can be determined at compilation.

So basically you would expect to cast `IFunny<string>` to a `IFunny<DataTable>`, for example, which is not going to work.

Comment: Indeed. Mihirj's answer is more detailed :)

Comment: There is no relationship (between TOther and T) that can be determined at compilation time, but there is a good chance that a relationship exists at runtime. So why does the compiler prevent the cast?